# Why I got "Cannot convet type generic List<int>"?

Tags: c#, list

I am getting this error about && cannot be applied to the operands of type bool and Ienumerable.

I am using two where one where is with the main list object and the second where is with the list object within the object.

Any help on this would be great.

```
TemplateNoteConditionStatusModel.Add(new TemplateNoteConditionStatusModel()
{
  Id = 1,
  Target = "CC"
});

TemplateNoteConditionStatusModel.Add(new TemplateNoteConditionStatusModel()
{
  Id = 2,
  Target = "DD"
});


var TemplateNoteModel = new TemplateNoteModel()
{
  Id = 1,
  Content = "AA",
  Conditions = TemplateNoteConditionStatusModel
};

var TemplateNote = new List<TemplateNoteModel>();

TemplateNote.Add(TemplateNoteModel);

string removeAgentDisease = "DD";
//Error Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type Bool and IErnumerable
TemplateNote = TemplateNote.Where(x => x.Content == "AA" 
                                        && x.Conditions.Where(v => v.Target == removeAgentDisease))
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Replace `x.Conditions.Where(v => v.Target == "removeAgentDisease")` by `x.Conditions.Any(v => v.Target == "removeAgentDisease")`

Comment: `x.Conditions.Any` Would not remove  that item right? Would I need to add remove to the end?

Comment: I was trying to return a collection base on the two conditions one conditions was in the main list object and the other was in the sub list object

Comment: so it should remove the  `Target = "CC"` and it my sample it is not removing it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`x.Conditions.Where(v => v.Target == removeAgentDisease)` returns collection of items. your statement `x.content == "AA" && someCollection` does not compute.

If you want to select notes which has certain content and a condition `removeAgentDisease` you would want something like:

<s>x => x.Content == "AA" && x.Conditions.Any(v => v.Target == removeAgentDisease)</s>

After trying to figure out whats going on in OP head I think I got the idea. To filter the collection where content is `AA` and Target is NOT `DD`

```
TemplateNote = TemplateNote
  .Where(x => x.Content == "AA" && !x.Conditions.Any(v => v.Target == removeAgentDisease))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I dont think the `x.Conditions.Any` is removing that item from the collection

Comment: It does, because it's part of the predicate of the outer `.Where`

Comment: any is not removing anything. the Where does. anyway. try it first before we go into a debate. thanks

Comment: yeah i got it now.. his original "code" :) is wrong twice. he wants to avoid `removeAgentDisease`